# AngularJS view doesn't get updated

Tags: angularjs

I have the attribute socketStatus in my scope, which is updated. The view doesn't recognize the update.

controller:

```
var socket = io.connect(localStorage.serverURL);
$scope.socketState = "not connected";
socket.on('connect', function(){
    $scope.socketState = "connected";
    socket.emit('register', 'clients', function(confirm){
        if(confirm)
             $scope.socketState = "entered room";
    });
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    $scope.socketState = "disconnected";
});
```

view:

```
{{socketState}}
```

the view alway shows "not connected" although the socket is connected and the room is entered.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.socketState = "entered room";
        });
```

Comment: the result is {{sockteState}}. I don't even get the first initialized value.

Comment: @marcel, then you haven't even included the AngularJS library! The `{{ }}` should not show up irrespective of the variable inside if AngularJS is running.

Comment: It only appears if I work with $scope.$apply .. otherwise it shows the correct value of socketState. If I use Nareks code, I get the curly brackets.

Comment: can you bring it in fiddle ?